# testing error is less than training error

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

i'm working with time series forecasting using RNN.

First, I fine-tuned hyper-parameters using genetic algorithm, then when I evaluate my selected model using test set, it gives me the following errors :

Train RMSE: 0.4700

Train RMSPE: 6.8745

Test RMSE: 0.2379

Test RMSPE: 3.3740

AS you can see, the testing errors is lower than training errors. What is that supposed to be mean? Did i do something wrong or it just normal?

Comment: Your test set is not diversified enough. Another possibility is that your train set contains badly labeled or very noisy examples

Comment: Are you computing the errors correctly? Are you using disjoint training/test sets? How big are they?

Comment: my training set contains 180 example and test set contains 46 examples